# Fancy fieldset legend

Tags: css, legend, fieldset, legend-properties

I am trying to html'ify a design in which a video has a border around it, and on the border a title.  The perfect way to accomplish this is with a fieldset and legand tag, however, I need to get fancy with the styling,  anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this, while maintaining compatibility with ie7+, firefox, and chrome??

Fame 1:
[image: Desired look of one frame]

Frame 2:
[image: Desired look of second frame]

Comment: the `<fieldset>` tag semantically is a really bad solution in this case

Comment: ^ agreed, just can't think of another way to get a label over a border and cause the border to go transparent for the duration of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ekgd/)

***HTML***

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <h2> Some lorem ipsum text title </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 25px;
    background: #000;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 5%;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: yellow;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    background: #000;
}
```